# Grails atmosphere plugin not working with Tomcat

Tags: grails, log4j, tomcat7, atmosphere

After including atmosphere plugin to my grails application

(only added following to BuildConfig.groovy)

```
compile ":atmosphere:0.4.2.3"
```

Application start normaly when running it with command

```
grails run-app
```

But application is not starting if I deploy it Tomcat server (7.0.30)

I am getting following in tomcat logs

```
log4j:ERROR Error initializing log4j: Implementing class
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2904)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1681)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.log4j.Log4jConfig.createConsoleAppender(Log4jConfig.groovy:220)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.log4j.Log4jConfig.configure(Log4jConfig.groovy:189)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.log4j.Log4jConfig.initialize(Log4jConfig.groovy:72)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.log4j.web.util.Log4jConfigListener.contextInitialized(Log4jConfigListener.java:48)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:963)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1600)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
2013-04-17 15:39:57,436 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
2013-04-17 15:39:57,449 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] - Context initialization failed
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.context.ConfigurableWebApplicationContext.setId(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:376) ~[spring-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293) ~[spring-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:69) [grails-web-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111) [spring-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791) [catalina.jar:7.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285) [catalina.jar:7.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901) [catalina.jar:7.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877) [catalina.jar:7.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618) [catalina.jar:7.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:963) [catalina.jar:7.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1600) [catalina.jar:7.0.30]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_21]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) [na:1.7.0_21]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) [na:1.7.0_21]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_21]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_21]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [na:1.7.0_21]
2013-04-17 15:39:57,453 ERROR [StackTrace] - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.context.ConfigurableWebApplicationContext.setId(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:376) ~[spring-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293) ~[spring-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:69) ~[grails-web-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111) [spring-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791) [catalina.jar:7.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285) [catalina.jar:7.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901) [catalina.jar:7.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877) [catalina.jar:7.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618) [catalina.jar:7.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:963) [catalina.jar:7.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1600) [catalina.jar:7.0.30]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_21]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) [na:1.7.0_21]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) [na:1.7.0_21]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_21]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_21]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [na:1.7.0_21]
2013-04-17 15:39:57,454 ERROR [StackTrace] - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.context.ConfigurableWebApplicationContext.setId(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_21]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) [na:1.7.0_21]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) [na:1.7.0_21]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_21]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_21]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [na:1.7.0_21]
2013-04-17 15:39:57,454 ERROR [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader] - Error initializing the application: org.springframework.web.context.ConfigurableWebApplicationContext.setId(Ljava/lang/String;)V
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.context.ConfigurableWebApplicationContext.setId(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_21]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) [na:1.7.0_21]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) [na:1.7.0_21]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_21]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_21]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [na:1.7.0_21]
2013-04-17 15:39:57,455 ERROR [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader] - Error initializing Grails: org.springframework.web.context.ConfigurableWebApplicationContext.setId(Ljava/lang/String;)V
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.context.ConfigurableWebApplicationContext.setId(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_21]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) [na:1.7.0_21]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) [na:1.7.0_21]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_21]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_21]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [na:1.7.0_21]
Apr 17, 2013 3:39:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
```

Any idea how to solve problem ?

Comment: add this to BuildConfig grails.tomcat.nio = true and see if that works.

Comment: It was added and it was not working.